# Oracle Database Encryption without ASO

Tags: oracle, encryption

The situation is that we can only use Oracle Standard Edition. However, we also need to encrypt certain fields (or maybe the whole tablespace).

Is there any way we can encrypt the database / certain fields but are still able to do a wildcard search, for e.g.

```
select * from enc_table where enc_col like 'j%'
```

The requirement is not so strict that we *have* to use like, we could use a function say

```
select * from enc_table where search_like(enc_col, 'j%')
```

Comment: Question: What would be the point of encryption, in such a case?  In order for the DB to do a search like that, it'd need to be able to decrypt the data, which means it needs to have the key.  At that point, what keeps me from simply convincing the DB to return the cleartext (or...just as bad, if not worse...the key)?

Comment: @cHao, seems legit to me. There's no reason for the user to know the key; you could have it encapsulated in a view or procedure.

Comment: @John, do you already have your encrypt/decrypt routines? Why not create a function `search_like` which decrypts the column, checks whether it is `LIKE p2`, and returns some non-null value if it matches? Performance wouldn't be great, mind you (it'd have to check each and every row in the table).

Comment: @cHao, the reason behind given to us is simply "physical security" such that when the hard disk is stolen, the data is still a bit protected.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, yeah. We have thought about it. However, the data is around 1.8M and growing and a full table scan will not be acceptable to the user.

Comment: @John: Problem is, *the server would still have to be able to decrypt the data.*  Which means the key used to encrypt it must be available, and probably stored locally.  Encryption would have little to no effect if the data and the decryption key are both readily available at the same location.  You'd have to separate them somehow...and that means not having the key readily and directly available to the machine the data's on.  (Perhaps if the client provided a key as part of starting the connection...perhaps.  But that seems like it would make transparent decryption much more difficult.)

Comment: As for how to do it...if i could do absolutely anything i wanted, i'd consider having the column (and its index) in a separate file and encrypting the whole file with some type of block cipher.  You could decrypt it once and keep it in non-paged memory, and get both performance and what little security transparent decryption could offer (which is not much at all, but eh).  Don't know what Oracle offers to that end, though.

Comment: @cHao, for the keys, please be assured that the keys are safely stored as they are planning to use an HSM.